Suitable Amazon Lex Slot type for Booking or Reservation Number, Example (A4F93C)
I am trying to build a bot for flight statuses that will accept 6 charactors booking and reservation numbers.
But I am bot sure which slot type to chose.
I also want to make sure the Booking or Reservation number should be 6 charactors.
I tried to select custom slot type Amazon.AlphaNumeric with regix [0-9][A-Z]{6}, but this doesnt work for me.
thanks in advance for the help.
